# Append a text below the other in TextBlock.Text object

Tags: c#, append, string-concatenation, textblock

I have the following text generated in a TextBlock:

```cs
            if (result == true)
            {
                FileNameTextBox.Text = openFileDlg.FileName;
                TextBlock1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDlg.FileName); //For example "Hello World"
                TextBlock1.Text.Append(System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(openFileDlg.FileName).ToString()); //For example "2020-18-09"
                Debug.WriteLine("Txt file contents!");
            }
```

Output:

```cs
"Hello World"
"2020-18-09"
```

I want to generate both texts: (a) the content of txt file and (b) the date the file was created. How can I append those two texts?

Comment: @OlivierRogier: this question isn't _about_ Winforms, or any specific GUI API. It's about concatenating strings. You even acknowledge as much in your posted answer. All of the APIs' `TextBox` controls work the same: text with newline characters inserted between lines results in lines displayed with line breaks. We don't need yet another answer saying the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Append` method just append text at the end of the chars array, that said, at end of the string like using the `+` concatenation operator.

To have a new line break, you need to add it:

```
TextBlock1.Text.Append(Environment.NewLine + SomeDateText);
```

Be carefull that if the file has an empty line, you will have a blank line.

Thus to be sure to have only one new line, write for example that or anything you like:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDlg.FileName);

if ( !lines.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine) )
  lines += Environment.NewLine;

TextBlock1.Text = lines + System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(openFileDlg.FileName).ToString();
```

Using that you control better the thing and how many blank line you eventually want.